# How to disable screen in no gui mode

Tags: command-line, display

Hi yearsterday i installed ubuntu 22 desktop on my laptop. I want to use it as home server for hosting some stuff for me family and frends. I turned off gui bcs i dont need it, but display is still on. Is there any command that allow me to disable display on desktop version? I tried many commands and every time i got one or other error.

Thx for response!